# XSLT not closing META and IMG tags

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have used the XML transformation to create HTML and I'm using XML worker to convert html to PDF. I'm getting a **Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag img** error since the HTML created through XML rendering doesn't have META, IMG and HR tag closed.Can you please help me with XML code changes so that I can have close tag for IMG, META and HR.

XML used.

```
Source xml = new StreamSource(new File("C:\\Reports\\ERseouce.xml"));
Source xslt = new StreamSource("C:\\Reports\\ExecutionReport_source.xsl");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Reports\\ExecutionReport_source.html");
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trasform = tFactory.newTransformer(xslt);
trasform.transform(xml, new StreamResult(sw));
fw.write(sw.toString());
fw.close();
```

xslt code

```
<xsl:template match="ROOT">
<html>
<head>
        <img style="float: left;" src="logo.gif" alt="logo" />
        <h1 style="font-size:60px;text-align: center;">Test Execution 
Report</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@script_name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@test_date" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@total_pass_count" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@total_fail_count" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

HTML output:

```
<html>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<head>
    <img style="float: left;" src="logo.gif" alt="logo" >
    <h1 style="font-size:60px;text-align: center;">Test Execution 
Report</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>SupplierInquiry</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2/02/2018 19:28:43 PM EST (UTC -5:00)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You can't put `img` and `h1` tags inside the `<head>,,,</head>` section.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Good point.  I've updated [*my answer below*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48819449/290085) to show fixed HTML in the XSLT.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
```

to the top-level your stylesheet to ensure that all tags are closed in the output markup.  You may prefer that the output be indented, as the default for XML is "no":

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

---

### Additional notes:

1. The HTML template in your XSLT will produce invalid HTML (thanks,
   @JimGarrison); `img` and `h1` are not allowed inside of `head`. 
   Here's a fix:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="ROOT">
       <html>
         <head>
           <meta name="description" content="Results of system1 testing"/>
           <title>Test Execution Report</title>
          </head>
         <body>
           <img style="float: left;" src="logo.gif" alt="logo" />
           <h1 style="font-size:60px;text-align: center;">Test Execution
           Report</h1>
           <table>
             <tr>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="@script_name" /></td>
             </tr>
             <!- ... -->
           </table>
         </body>
       </html>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
2. The reason that you were getting unclosed `meta` and `img` elements
   is that without an explicit `xsl:output/method`, HTML serialization
   is used given the `html` root element of your output tree; otherwise
   the default would have been to use XML serialization. (Thanks,
   @MichaelKay.)
3. For `xsl:output/@method="xml"`, XSLT 1.0 won't generate

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
   ```

   but it will propagate explicitly stated meta tags such as

   ```
   <meta name="description" content="Results of system1 testing"/>
   ```

   For XSLT 2.0, use `xsl:output/@method="xhtml"` to get both the
   auto-generated `meta` element and closing tags.  (Thanks again,
   @MichaelKay.)

Comment: Note that the default serialization method is html if the outermost element of the result tree is "html", otherwise it is XML. Note also that the meta tag won't be generated at all if you use method="xml"; with XSLT 2.0 you can also ask for method="xhtml" which gives well-formed XML output but still generates the meta element.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Answer updated to include your helpful notes.  Thank you!